# scala/play - Conversion of JSValue Data Types to generic equivalents

Tags: json, scala, playframework-2.0

I've just begun learning Scala and the Play framework, and I have transformed some JSON data into a standard Map.

My map conversion code looks something like this (Where JsValue is that of the [play framework](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.x/api/scala/index.html#play.api.libs.json.JsValue))

```
val doc = json.as[Map[String, JsValue]]
```

The question I have now is **whether there is something that can iterate over this map and return generic types (String, Array, Int/Long, Bool, etc), in place of their JsValue subclass equivalents?**

ie. `String`s in place of `JsString`s, `Boolean`s in place of `JsBoolean`s etc.

Presumably, it would not be difficult to write something to do this, but I wondered if this functionality is implemented in some standard way that I can just pull off the shelf and use.

Thanks

Comment: YOu need to go through the documentation (http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaJsonCombinators). Play has reads/writes using which you can do it easily

Comment: Note that the type you'd get is `Map[String, Any]`, with which you can do little useful.